# Function does not see locals in exec with supplied locals

Tags: python, scope, indirection

Consider this working code:

```py
x=123

def printx():
     print(x)
```

If I execute `printx()` the output would be `123` as `x` value exists in `locals()` and `printx` sees that.

I can also get `x` value like this:

```
locals()["x"]
```

But I need to run my function in [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) with global and local parameters supplied, so I wrote this code, which should be identical in purpose to the first snippet:

```py
glo = dict()
loc = dict()
exec('x=123', glo, loc)
exec('def printx():\n    print(x)', glo, loc)
```

However, when I call `printx()` I get this error:

```
exec('printx()', glo, loc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in printx
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Yet both `loc["x"]` and `eval('x', glo, loc)` return `123` as expected.

How can I make locals and globals available for my `printx` function?
I want `printx` to behave the same in `exec` with context?

Comment: *"I need to run my function in `exec`"*  -  you probably don't

Comment: @TomKarzes not sure what you're talking about? I started `python` interpreter and executed the code I posted. There's nothing else. It's Python 3.8.7.

Comment: @rfg Sorry, you're right, at the top-level `locals()` shows global variable bindings - I had forgotten that.  You can compare it with `globals()`.  In fact, at the top-level, they return the exact same `dict`, and in fact `locals() is globals()` is true at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a local dict is provided, "eval" runs in that local namespace.  All changes go in that local namespace.  You can see that by printing `loc` after your commands.  Both `x` and `printx` are in that namespace.  Calling a function establishes a new local namespace.  Python doesn't nest namespaces, so all it has available is its new (empty) local namespace and the global namespace, and `x` is in neither of those.

You should probably run your first two `eval`s with the global namespace only.  That way, your code will work, even if it is a horrible way to do Python programming.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Technically, Python will nest namespaces (it's how closures work), but it's not something `eval`/`exec` supports; the locals aren't treated as a closure scope around any functions defined in the string being executed. C'est la vie.